# Find where ID not in array of the model

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a UserModel with the following structure:

```
{
    invitations: ['c'],
    projects: [ 'a', 'b' ],
    _id: 61224277e209b832b08f46aa,
    name: 'User A',
  },{
    invitations: ['a'],
    projects: [ 'b'],
    _id: 61224277e209b832b08f46aa,
    name: 'User B',
  }
```

The invitations and projects array refers to a Project.
A User is invited/member of project X if the invitation/member array of the user contains the _id of X

For a given projectId, I want to get all the users who are not invited or who are not in the project.

For example, it should return User B for project 'c' and UserA and B for project 'd'.

How can I do this using mongoose?

Thank's

Comment: The question is not clear. Where is project C and D? Please update the question..

Comment: @varman Edited! If it's not still clear tell me

Comment: It's not clear for me, myabe I've missunderstood, but is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0o0gT0P2ZOk) what are you looking for?

Comment: Hi! Thank's you that is exactly what I need!